# Firefox setting to allow Web Notifications to stay open longer (or indefinitely)

Tags: firefox, browser, web, notifications, default-settings

By default, Firefox displays Web Notifications for about half a minute before automatically hiding them.

Is there a way to increase the amount of time that they are displayed before auto-hiding them?

Alternatively, is there a way to prevent them from auto-hiding at all?

Comment: After much digging around, I finally found evidence that confirms it's hardcoded to 20 seconds: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/search?q=ALERT_DURATION_IMMEDIATE. Will continue looking for a way to change this though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Firefox, notifications are [hardcoded to close after 20 seconds](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/search?q=ALERT_DURATION_IMMEDIATE). To allow notifications to stay open indefinitely until the user closes them, toggle the `dom.webnotifications.requireinteraction.enabled` flag. Navigate to `about:config` in the address bar to do this.

The default value for `dom.webnotifications.requireinteraction.enabled` is **false** so it does not require user interaction to dismiss notifications. Set this to **true**.

Now the caveat is, the service sending the notification also has to use the [`requireInteraction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/requireInteraction) property for this setting to have any effect.

You can test it here: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/notifications/requireInteraction.html. One of the notifications disappears after 20 seconds and the other stays open. If the `dom.webnotifications.requireinteraction.enabled` flag is set to **false**, both will close after 20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I made a small edit to your great answer.  If for any reason the edit is not in line with the facts, please revert or edit.  Thanks again!

Comment: MDN has a code example slightly simpler the the provided link here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requireInteraction

Comment: This works for me, but after 20 seconds, when I click the notification, it closes...it doesn't opet the link in the notification. How to fix that?

Comment: As of a recent update, it appears that the default has been changed to true, I've had to manually set it to false as YouTube is sending updates that don't disappear automatically but other sties are working normally.